# call javascript function on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to set a cookie value when user clicks on a link.
I am using the following code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function changeLang(lang) {
            $.cookie('myCulture', lang);
            window.location.reload();
            return false;
        }
    });

</script>
```

HTML

```
  <a href="#" onclick="changeLang('da-DK')"><img src="../../Content/images/danishFlag.png" height="35px" width="35px"/></a>

  <a href="#" onclick="changeLang('sv-SE')"><img src="../../Content/images/swedishFlag.png" height="35px" width="35px"/></a>
```

It looks like very simple code, but when I click on the link, there is an error in the browser.
It says.

```
ReferenceError: changeLang is not defined   

changeLang("da-DK");
```

Where am I doing wrong??

Comment: relocate your function to out of document ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are defining the function inside the document ready scope, so it's not global therefore not available in the global scope

define it as a global simply by removing the var declaration or using window.changeLang = function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

       changeLang = function(lang) {
            document.cookie = 'myCulture' + lang;
            window.location.reload();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

define function outside of the jquery block

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});

function changeLang(lang) {
        $.cookie('myCulture', lang);
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: TypeError: $.cookie is not a function

Comment: yes i have the file. i took it from here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Please do not attach js functions in html like this. 
You're using jquery so just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function changeLang() {
        $.cookie('myCulture', $(this).data('lang'));
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
    }
    $('.link').on('click', changeLang);
});
```

and then in html:

```
<a href="#" data-lang="da-DK">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the ChangeLang function to outside of the Document Ready section.
Also, if running in FireFox with Firebug you can experiment with executing the function directly from the Console.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});
function changeLang(lang) {
    document.cookie = 'myCulture=' + lang;
    window.location.reload();
    return false;
}
```

This will work for you.